# Customizing Workflow Task list 2013 form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, task-list

I have created SP designer workflow (sharepoint 2013 platform) with the custom list.
But what my issue is that, By default the task form (workflow task list 2013)  showing Approve, Rejection, save and cancel buttons. 
Here i have created my own content type and in which have added one Task outcome column with some 4 different statuses. So, If I changed to My content type which is showing dropdown control instead of Buttons?

I followed this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/09/14/how-to-manipulate-the-task-form-with-sharepoint-designer-for-new-task-actions.aspx)

How to show buttons instead of dropdown here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right in understanding you, you have created a custom content type that is being applied to your Task List for a 2013 workflow. However, your custom outcome choices are showing up as a dropdown, instead of as buttons.

Two fields are required to make the outcome field work properly:

- % Complete
- Task Status

Make sure that neither of these have been removed or are hidden.

Another factor could be the order of the columns. The outcome field always has to be at the very end.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Programming Girl, I don't know your answer is correct or not because it is too late. Now I'm working in different project. I'm sure I did set %Complete to hidden mode. Anyways thanks for the reply.